# Duvida com Bubble Sort

Tags: java

```
package AlgoritmosII;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Exercicio //BubbleSort

{

public static void main(String args[])
    {

        int troca, fim, i, aux, k;

        int tamanho = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("informe o tamanho do vetor"));

        int vetorOrdenar[] = new int[tamanho];
        for (i=0;i<=tamanho;i++) {
            vetorOrdenar[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe os " +tamanho+ " valores do vetor:"));
        }
        troca = 1;
        fim = tamanho - 1;
        while(troca==1)
        {
            troca = 0;
            for(i=0; i<fim;i++)
            {
                if (vetorOrdenar[i] > vetorOrdenar[i+1])
                {
                    aux = vetorOrdenar[i];
                    vetorOrdenar[i] = vetorOrdenar[i+1];
                    vetorOrdenar[i+1]=aux;
                    troca = 1;
                }
            }
            fim = fim - 1;
        }
        for (k=0;k<=tamanho;k++){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,vetorOrdenar[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Meu objetivo seria pedir ao usuário que diga o tamanho do vetor e os valores que seriam colocados nele, depois disso ele seria colocado em ordem crescente, no final ele deveria mostrar a forma ordenada do vetor.

Answer (score 1):

Nesses dois trechos

```
for (i=0;i<=tamanho;i++)
```

e

```
for (k=0;k<=tamanho;k++){
```

você usou o comparador `<=` para limitar o valor da variável ao tamanho do vetor. Como em Java o vetor começa com índice `0` o último elemento do vetor terá o índice `tamanho - 1`, ex: se o tamanho for 4 o último índice é 3, implicando que sua comparação permita a iteração seja aplicada em um índice não existente.

No último laço

```
for (k=0;k<=tamanho;k++){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,vetorOrdenar[i]);
            i++;
        }
```

você itera sobre a váriável `k` mas usa a variável `i` como índice cujo o valor foi deixado como `fim - 1` no laço anterior.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Exercicio //BubbleSort

{

public static void main(String args[])
    {

        int troca, fim, i, aux, k;

        int tamanho = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("informe o tamanho do vetor"));

        int vetorOrdenar[] = new int[tamanho];
        for (i=0;i<tamanho;i++) {// Troque do comparador <= para <
            vetorOrdenar[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe os " +tamanho+ " valores do vetor:"));
        }
        troca = 1;
        fim = tamanho - 1;
        while(troca==1)
        {
            troca = 0;
            for(i=0;i<fim;i++)
            {
                if (vetorOrdenar[i] > vetorOrdenar[i+1])
                {
                    aux = vetorOrdenar[i];
                    vetorOrdenar[i] = vetorOrdenar[i+1];
                    vetorOrdenar[i+1]=aux;
                    troca = 1;
                }
            }
            fim = fim - 1;
        }
        for (k=0;k<tamanho;k++){// Troque do comparador <= para <
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,vetorOrdenar[k]); //use a variável k como índice
        }
    }
}
```